# Como reducir el contenido a mostrar de un párrafo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Estoy desarrollando un un sistema en codeigniter en el cual una de las funcionalidades es mostrar un una especie de post de los contenido variados, la cuestión es que al ingresar a la vista principal me tiene que mostrar una lista de los post publicados, lo que quiero logra es que al mostar el contenido del texto no lo muestre del todo, solo una porción de este.

Como pueden ver se muestra todo el contenido del texto, lo cual no tendria que ser asi, la idea es que hasta ciertas lineas de texto muestre unos puntos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo mas o menos asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría decirme el como lograrlo.

Comment: ¿El texto de la descripción puede contener HTML o sólo texto plano? ¿Quieres contar el número de palabras directamente o el número de caracteres pero teniendo cuidado en que la última palabra quede entera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que deseas se puede hacer con CSS mediante el uso de las propiedades CSS [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Values) con el valor `ellipsis`, [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Values) con un valor `hidden` junto con una de las dos opciones:

- Una única línea de texto: [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Valores) con valor `nowrap`.
- Un número determinado de líneas: [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) con los valores **no estándar** `-webkit-box`, `-moz-box` y `box` y las propiedades **no estándar** [`box-orient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient) con valor `vertical` y por último fijamos el número de líneas a mostrar con la propiedad **no estándar** [`-webkit-line-clamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp) con el valor deseado (en el siguiente ejemplo, `3` líneas).

```css
.clase {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.ejemplo1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ejemplo2 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  line-clamp: 3;
}
.ejemplo3 {
  display: box;
  box-orient: vertical;
  line-clamp: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="clase ejemplo1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tincidunt tellus sed risus porttitor, ac aliquam turpis vestibulum. Pellentesque mollis, augue ut porta eleifend, lacus velit dignissim nulla, et rutrum turpis elit et sem. Praesent lobortis mauris turpis, ac egestas magna auctor a. Nulla vitae porttitor ante. Pellentesque accumsan nec turpis commodo ultrices. In eget lobortis lorem. Proin vehicula, felis eu hendrerit egestas, sem libero pellentesque turpis, sed dapibus justo urna a metus. Curabitur pharetra ut quam nec laoreet. Sed eu velit vitae sem varius aliquam maximus sed nisl. Integer dignissim condimentum orci at tempus. Praesent a facilisis magna, ut suscipit libero. Maecenas ut feugiat enim. Vestibulum justo nisi, posuere in massa vel, porttitor laoreet neque.</div>
<div class="clase ejemplo2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tincidunt tellus sed risus porttitor, ac aliquam turpis vestibulum. Pellentesque mollis, augue ut porta eleifend, lacus velit dignissim nulla, et rutrum turpis elit et sem. Praesent lobortis mauris turpis, ac egestas magna auctor a. Nulla vitae porttitor ante. Pellentesque accumsan nec turpis commodo ultrices. In eget lobortis lorem. Proin vehicula, felis eu hendrerit egestas, sem libero pellentesque turpis, sed dapibus justo urna a metus. Curabitur pharetra ut quam nec laoreet. Sed eu velit vitae sem varius aliquam maximus sed nisl. Integer dignissim condimentum orci at tempus. Praesent a facilisis magna, ut suscipit libero. Maecenas ut feugiat enim. Vestibulum justo nisi, posuere in massa vel, porttitor laoreet neque.</div>
<div class="clase ejemplo3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tincidunt tellus sed risus porttitor, ac aliquam turpis vestibulum. Pellentesque mollis, augue ut porta eleifend, lacus velit dignissim nulla, et rutrum turpis elit et sem. Praesent lobortis mauris turpis, ac egestas magna auctor a. Nulla vitae porttitor ante. Pellentesque accumsan nec turpis commodo ultrices. In eget lobortis lorem. Proin vehicula, felis eu hendrerit egestas, sem libero pellentesque turpis, sed dapibus justo urna a metus. Curabitur pharetra ut quam nec laoreet. Sed eu velit vitae sem varius aliquam maximus sed nisl. Integer dignissim condimentum orci at tempus. Praesent a facilisis magna, ut suscipit libero. Maecenas ut feugiat enim. Vestibulum justo nisi, posuere in massa vel, porttitor laoreet neque.</div>
```

El principal problema que supone usar un determinado número de líneas es que podría suponer problemas de compatibilidad presente o futura con los navegadores o, como dicen las páginas enlazadas, desaparezca en un futuro `-webkit-line-clamp` en favor de `line-clamp`, por lo que habría que contemplar todas las opciones hasta que se estabilice el estándar (si llega a convertirse en estándar, que tampoco es seguro).

**Ventajas y desventajas:**

- Ventaja: CSS sencillo (aunque debamos duplicar o triplicar algunas propiedades CSS para mantener compatibilidad hacia delante y hacia atrás.
- Desventaja: al no ser un estándar no se sabe qué ocurrirá con él en el futuro.

---

Para el resto de navegadores se puede usar el siguiente truco CSS para mostrar los mismos puntos suspensivos en un margen dependiendo de si se llega o no al límite de líneas:

```css
.clase {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /* La altura por defecto es 1.1em, podemos cambiarla */
  line-height: 1.2em;
  /* Calculamos la altura máxima (1.2em x 3 = 3.6em) */
  max-height: 3.6em;
  /* Impedimos que los puntos suspensivos se superpongan al texto */
  padding-right: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* Los puntos suspensivos que aparecerán si se desborda */
.clase:before {
  content: '…';
  position: absolute;
  /* Los posicionamos abajo a la derecha */
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
/* Superponemos un espacio en blanco sobre los puntos suspensivos
cuando no se llega al tamaño máximo */
.clase:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* Posicionamos el "tapón" blanco a la derecha en la última línea */
  right: 0;
  /* El tapón es un cuadrado de 1em de altura, anchura y de color blanco */
  background: white;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="clase">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tincidunt tellus sed risus porttitor, ac aliquam turpis vestibulum. Pellentesque mollis, augue ut porta eleifend, lacus velit dignissim nulla, et rutrum turpis elit et sem. Praesent lobortis mauris turpis, ac egestas magna auctor a. Nulla vitae porttitor ante. Pellentesque accumsan nec turpis commodo ultrices. In eget lobortis lorem. Proin vehicula, felis eu hendrerit egestas, sem libero pellentesque turpis, sed dapibus justo urna a metus. Curabitur pharetra ut quam nec laoreet. Sed eu velit vitae sem varius aliquam maximus sed nisl. Integer dignissim condimentum orci at tempus. Praesent a facilisis magna, ut suscipit libero. Maecenas ut feugiat enim. Vestibulum justo nisi, posuere in massa vel, porttitor laoreet neque.</div>
<div class="clase">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div class="clase">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />Cras tincidunt tellus sed risus porttitor, ac aliquam turpis vestibulum.</div>
<div class="clase">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />Cras tincidunt tellus sed risus porttitor, ac aliquam turpis vestibulum.<br />Pellentesque mollis, augue ut porta eleifend, lacus velit dignissim nulla, et rutrum turpis.</div>
```

El funcionamiento, ingenioso, es el siguiente:

- Posicionamos los puntos suspensivos (marco verde) siempre abajo a la derecha.
- Posicionamos en la última línea de texto (marco naranja) un recuadro blanco a la derecha que tapará a los puntos suspensivos siempre que la última línea del texto se muestre dentro del contenedor (es decir, que no se haya desbordado el contenido).

**Ventajas y desventajas:**

- Ventaja: CSS compatible con cualquier navegador.
- Desventaja: Se pierde el ancho de un carácter en el borde derecho para que los puntos suspensivos no queden superpuestos al texto.

Answer (score 6):

Puedes usar **CSS**:

```
.text {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   line-height: 16px;
   max-height: 32px;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Puedes ver aquí un ejemplo:

```css
body {
   margin: 40px;
}

.text {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   line-height: 16px;     /* fallback */
   max-height: 32px;      /* fallback */
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus nulla eu dolor. Nulla porta bibendum lectus quis euismod. Aliquam volutpat ultricies porttitor. Cras risus nisi, accumsan vel cursus ut, sollicitudin vitae dolor. Fusce scelerisque eleifend lectus in bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia egestas felis a volutpat.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve desarrollando un aplicativo y me encontré con el mismo inconveniente, la solución fue utilizar la función: substr() de PHP.

Dicha funcionalidad recibe tres parámetros, 1) la cadena de texto (campo que llega desde la BD), 2) desde donde inicia que sería la posición cero (0), 3) hasta donde termina (cantidad de caracteres).

```
<?php echo substr($row['contenido'], 0, 150)?>
```

[Función `substr` en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

Espero te sirva, es el modo más fácil de solucionar.